# Why the behavior for ChangeListener<T> is different depending on the T parameter

Tags: java-8, javafx-8

Consider the following program:

```
import javafx.beans.property.ListProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleListProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;

/**
 *
 * @author kachna
 */
public class ListPropertyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringProperty p = new SimpleStringProperty();
        p.addListener((obs, old, nw) -> {
            System.out.println("String Property; oldString: " + old + ", newString: " + nw);
        });
        p.set("1");

        ListProperty<String> listProperty = new SimpleListProperty<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList());
        listProperty.addListener((obs, old, nw) -> {
            System.out.println("ListProperty; oldList:  " + old + ", newList: " + nw);

        });

        listProperty.addAll("1", "2", "3");

    }
}
```

running the program gives the following output:

```
String Property; oldString: null, newString: 1
ListProperty; oldList:  [1, 2, 3], newList: [1, 2, 3]
```

As you can see the old value is:

1. `null` when `T` is a `String`
2. A value that equals to the new value when `T` is an
   `ObservableList<String>`

Comment: Looks like the general problem with mutable data to me. The list instance *is* the same when you change its contents, so the old and new value are references to the same list, but since the notification happens after the modification, the list shows the new contents, regardless of which reference you use to access it, of course.

Comment: I debugged that and it looks like this comes from `com.sun.javafx.binding.ListExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(change)`. This method gives the old value and new value the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug: `ListProperty` should not fire changed events at all when the contents of the wrapped list change: it should only fire list changed events. In other words, you should only be able to detect the changes from

```
listProperty.addAll("1", "2", "3");
```

with the listener

```
listProperty.addListener((ListChangeListener<? extends String> change) -> {
    // e.g.
    while (change.next()) {
        if (change.wasAdded()) {
            System.out.println(change.getAddedSubList());
        }
    }
});
```

The listener you registered should only fire when you change the actual reference, e.g. with

```
listProperty.setValue(FXCollections.observableArrayList("1","2","3"));
```

This is probably a bug that can't be fixed without breaking a lot of existing code: I don't know if there are plans to rectify this.

What is actually happening is that the change event is being fired, but the old value and new value refer to the same list (because the actual wrapped list reference hasn't changed). So, of course, the `toString()` method returns the same value whether you call it from `old` or `nw`, and gives the current content of the list.

Comment: I think your reasoning is correct. but I have read the following ( from Learn Javafx8 ebook): `When the content of the list changes,
the changed() method of ChangeListeners receives the reference to the same list as the old and new
value. If the wrapped reference of the ObservableList is replaced with a new one, this method receives
references of the old list and the new list.`

Comment: Yes, OK, that's basically the same as what I said. However, I think the event should not be fired in the first case, because the wrapped reference has not changed.